# Scroll to specific item in Checkbox List using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, scroll

Hi have a Listview that I populate with alphabet letters. When a letter is clicked it looks for the first word in the checkbox list that starts with the alphabet letter. The value of the checkboxlist is then used as the parameter to which I have to scroll to.

I created a simple jsFiddle to test:

[Checkbox list scroll to item](http://jsfiddle.net/Kerieks/j36dd5d5/)

The fiddle is working fine. However, in my project I am getting the following error:

```
    0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference
```

This is what I did in code:

ASP.Net

```
    <div id="dialogEscalate" >
    <div id="MyDiv">
       <table>
        //other controls
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:ListView ID="lvLetters" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Value" OnItemCommand="rpAlphabetList_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelectAlphabet" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Value")%>' ></asp:LinkButton>                               
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>|</ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  style="vertical-align:top;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Escalate To: "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="escPersList" style="max-height:20px; height:200px; width:100%; min-width:400px; overflow-y:scroll;" >
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkEscalationList" CssClass="CheckBoxList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkEscalationList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    RepeatColumns="1" runat="server">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </div>                   
            </td>
        </tr>
        //other controls
        </table>
    <div>
    <div>
```

C#: (Checkboxlist value:EmailAddress and Text: EmailAddress + Name

```
    private void GenerateAlphabets()
    {
        List<ListItem> alphabets = new List<ListItem>();
        ListItem alphabet = new ListItem();
       // alphabet.Value = "ALL";
        alphabet.Selected = alphabet.Value.Equals(ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"]);
        alphabets.Add(alphabet);
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            alphabet = new ListItem();
            alphabet.Value = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i);
            alphabet.Selected = alphabet.Value.Equals(ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"]);
            alphabets.Add(alphabet);
        }

        lvLetters.DataSource = alphabets;
        lvLetters.DataBind();
    }
```

This is when I click on the Alphabet letters:

```
    protected void rpAlphabetList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataKey key = lvLetters.DataKeys[e.Item.DisplayIndex];
        string letterVal = (string)key["Value"];

        letterVal = letterVal.ToLower();

        foreach (ListItem li in chkEscalationList.Items)
        {
            string val = li.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim();

            if (val.StartsWith(letterVal))
            {
                string sScript = "scrollToPerson('" + val + "');";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "focusScript", sScript, true);

                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Then this is my jQuery:

```
    function scrollToPerson(word) {           
        var container = $('#MyDiv'),
        scrollTo = $('#"' + word + '"');

        container.animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
        });
```

What am I doing wrong on code side?

------------ UPDATE ------------
After applying the below solution the scrolling isn't working. 
The value that is passed through code side is the email. Thus selecting T form the list the first value in the list it has to scroll to is t*****@soxsa.co.za. When looking at the "Insect page" from Chrome/IE the id of that specific control is different:

[image: Element details]

I'm only a beginner with jquery, but I think the issue for not scrolling is the value I send through and the element id is different?

The new jQuery script is as follows:

```
   function scrollToPerson(word) {           
        var container = $('#escPersList'),
        scrollTo = $("'#" + word + "'");
        container.animate({ scrollTop: scrollTo.top });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should work for you just fine unless if it's not exactly what u are aiming at

```
container.animate({scrollTop:$('#"' + word + '"').top});
```

or this should be what you needed. this for the page to scroll to that element

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#"' + word + '"').top})
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, the error is not showing anymore, however, it is scrolling to where it needs to, any ideas? (the aim is for the first solution you provided thanks)

Comment: Thanks this is a total different issue. When viewing inspect page, I see the values are the same, but the client side id is something different, which I guess I need to match before it will find the correct word to scroll to?

Comment: how are the id's appearing different? could you post a snippet  what error u are getting here Pls.

Comment: Thanks I added an update above with the snippet.. there is no error though, just nothing is happening....

Comment: Hey bro you shared something while blurring some part of it. how can we vividly figure out what it's. i suggest u share a new update and the new updated text. cos i couldn't figure out if it was from chrome devtool or what?

Comment: I only blurred out the part of the email from the email addresses and one of the surname of the other part... this was from chrome, will update the new jquery script as is